# Как растянуть блок по высоте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Родительский блок `.wrapper` имеет высоту 100%. У дочернего блока `.info` высота не определена и может быть разной. Как растянуть дочерний блок `.wrp` на всю оставшуюся высоту родительского блока `.wrapper`?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}

.wrp {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.info {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrp"></div>
  <div class="info">Ты видел деву на скале<br />В одежде белой над волнами<br />Когда, бушуя в бурной мгле,<br />Играло море с берегами,<br />Когда луч молний озарял<br />Ее всечасно блеском алым<br />И ветер бился и летал<br />С ее летучим покрывалом?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью jquery или js

```
  var  height_wrapper = $('.wrapper').height(),
       height_info = $('.info').height(),
       height_wpr = height_wrapper-height_info;
  $('.wrp').css({'height': height_wpr});
```

**UPD**: Сейчас почти все современные браузеры поддерживают flexbox (детальней [тут](https://caniuse.com/?search=flexbox)), поэтому лучше делать через CSS (в ответах к этому вопросу есть пример)

Answer (score 7):

Решение на CSS с помощью flexbox ([поддержка браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox))

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrp {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: По caniuse.com flexbox с префиксами работает у 96.92% пользователей, так что, если не нужна поддержка IE9 и ниже, смело используйте.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с display: table

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;  
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}
.wrapper__item{
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: chocolate;
}
.wrapper__item--info {  
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__item">text 1</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item wrapper__item--info">
  Ты видел деву на скале
  </div>
</div>
```